# How to display data from database to drop-down list in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've tried to display data from the database `phpmyadmin` to the drop-down list in Wordpress but it's not working.

Here My Code :

```html
<select name="progress"  id="progress"  class="select-select2">
<option  value="">Select Progress</option>
<?php 
    $result=$wpdb->get_results("select * from wp_progress");
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $id_kta=$row->id_kta;
        $progress=$row->progress;
        echo '<option value='.$id_kta.'>'.$progress.'</option>';
    }
   ?>     
</select>
```

is there something wrong with my code? Can anyone help me please ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: _Note:_ Your database is not `phpmyadmin`, it's simply a MySQL database. PHPMyAdmin is just a web based management tool for managing MySQL-databases. You're application has no connection to PHPMyAdmin in any way.

Comment: Print the $result before the select just to double check that you are getting data from the database

Comment: it seems $result is not getting anything from database

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Oh I'm sorry I don't know that, so what should i do ? can you give me some example code ?

Comment: @DsRaj so I have to move the $ result before <select> or just duplicate it?

Comment: 1. Expand on _"is not working"_. No list is generated? Doesn't work when you select a value? You get errors? 2. Do a `var_dump($result)` and check what it actually contains. 3. What does the generated HTML from your code look like?

Comment: <? global $wpdb; 
$result=$wpdb->get_results("select * from wp_progress");
print_r($result);exit; ?
Add this before the select to verify that something is loading from database

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The problem is when I have run this code just display a blank page, nothing display anything. and no errors display in page. 
And I don't know why the drop-down list doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this code,

```html
<select name="progress"  id="progress"  class="select-select2">
<option  value="">Select Progress</option>
<?php 
    global $wpdb; 
    $result=$wpdb->get_results("select * from ".$wpdb->prefix."progress");
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $id_kta   = $row[id_kta];
        $progress = $row[progress];
        echo '<option value = '.$id_kta.'>'.$progress.'</option>';
    }
   ?>     
</select>
```

Comment: It's Working, Thanks you So Much. But you must change  `$id_kta   = $row[id_kta];$progress = $row[progress];` to this code   `$id_kta=$row->id_kta;$progress=$row->progress;` Thanks a lot